# writing a script to check if ssh tunneling is on

Tags: shell-script, ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

I have a ssh tunnel set up as follows:

```
ssh -N -L 1105:remote.server:25 office-machine&
```

I want to write a script to set up a check, say once a minute (which I can do using a cron job, perhaps), that will check whether this connection is up, otherwise it will set up the connection (if vpn is on).

What do I do to perform the check for the ssh tunnel?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I tried

```
autossh -N -L 1105:remote.server:25 office-machine&
```

but it exits. I suspect that the  options are correct. In fact the manpage/help indicates there is no -N and -L option, but only -f and -M.

Comment: Seems like you're reinventing `autossh`

Comment: never heard of it earlier, but it does exist. But can you let me know how to use this? Thanks!

Comment: Once you have it installed, just use `autossh` instead of `ssh` in the command above.

Comment: See above edits, thanks again!

Comment: Ah,  sorry, you need to specify an additional monitoring port for `autossh`. Pick some port N so that both N and N+1 are free, and use it with the `-M` option. e.g., `autossh -M 20000 -N -L 1105:remote.server:25 office-machine`.

Comment: thank you! so what would happen if VPN went down? the ssh is through VPN (does not "work" when there is no VPN connection). Btw, if you put this as an answer, I can accept it and give you credit. thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `autossh` for this. Quoting [the Ubuntu manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/autossh.1.html):

```
 autossh is a program to start a copy of ssh and monitor it, restarting it as necessary
 should it die or stop passing traffic.

 The original idea and the mechanism were from rstunnel (Reliable SSH Tunnel). With version
 1.2 of autossh the method changed: autossh uses ssh to construct a loop of ssh forwardings
 (one from local to remote, one from remote to local), and then sends test data that it
 expects to get back. (The idea is thanks to Terrence Martin.)
```

So an additional monitoring port must be specified `autossh`. Pick some port N so that both N and N+1 are free, and use it with the `-M` option, e.g.,

```
autossh -M 20000 -N -L 1105:remote.server:25 office-machine
```

You can also disable monitoring with `-M 0`. On Debian-based systems, `autossh` can pick a free port for monitoring automatically.

---

If your VPN connection dies, `autossh` should detect via the monitoring port that the SSH connection is no longer alive, and then try to restart it. After that:

```
Continued failures
 If the ssh connection fails and attempts to restart it fail in quick succession, autossh
 will start delaying its attempts to restart, gradually backing farther and farther off up to
 a maximum interval of the autossh poll time (usually 10 minutes).  autossh can be "prodded"
 to retry by signalling it, perhaps with SIGHUP ("kill -HUP").
```